# Query JSON data from HBASE using SPARK SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have a table in HBASE as

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rowkey        |      Name        |            marks                    |
|   1           |       ABC        | {"mathematics":"30","science":"50"} |
|   2           |       XYZ        | {"mathematics":"50","science":"90"} |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The JSON can be nested json. I want to query the table on the basis of JSON fields using SPARK SQL. So that I can query as "name where marks in science = 50". can I do this directly over HBASE or using apache Phoenix over HBASE

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON inside of HBase... You should have had a `marks` column family and a column within `marks` for each class. You can easily do that using either HBase or Phoenix. If you want to use JSON, then use MongoDB.